# Discord JS - Getting the nickname of a user who dm's the bot

Tags: discord.js

I want to get the server nickname of a user that is in the same server as the bot when the user dm's the bot.

I've tried: message.author.guild.members.get(message.author.id).displayName and message.author.displayName, 1st one crashes the bot, the 2nd returns the nickname as "undefined". For now I have it set to message.author.username, but this gives me the username, and I need the nickname.

```js
if(message.channel.type === "dm" && message.content === 'specific message') {

     let bicon = bot.user.displayAvatarURL;
     let botembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
     .setTitle("**Log**")
     .setDescription("**" + message.author.username + "** messaged me!")
     .setColor("#F54603")
     .setTimestamp()

     return bot.channels.get("584424339986710540").send(botembed);
```

I believe what needs to be done is, the bot retrieves the user ID from the user that DM's the bot, then searches for that user ID in the server and then get's the displayName. However, I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must specify from which guild the bot retrieves the user's nickname. The following code accomplishes that:

```js
let guild = client.guilds.get('serverID');
let member = guild.member(message.author);
let nickname = member ? member.displayName : null;
```

Comment: client.guilds.get is not a function, ig it is fetch now @Doteq

Comment: yeah get is no longer available, it's fetch and it's a promise, you can see my helper function at my answer FWIW

Answer (score 4):

You have all the information in the message, this is the helper function I used:

```js
const getAuthorDisplayName = async (msg) => {
  const member = await msg.guild.member(msg.author);
  return member ? member.nickname : msg.author.username;
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. It always prints out
`"ReferenceError: Cannot access 'guild' before initialization"` but I have defined it like this: 
`const bot = new Discord.Client(); const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get('guildID');`

Comment: guild member lookup also has changed since this answer was posted.  change to: await msg.guild.members.fetch(msg.author)