# tag a user using discord node js

Tags: node.js, discord

I want to make a command that tags a user when there name got mentoined. But now the bot only tags the username and not a nickname the person has in the server

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if(message.content === 'test'){
    message.channel.send("works")
    console.log("logged the message")
  }
})

client.on("message", message => {

const list = message.guild;
    list.members.cache.each(member => {
    pinging = member.user.id
  console.log(member.user.username)
         if(message.content.includes(member.user.username)){
          message.channel.send(`<@${pinging}>`)
         }
    })
  
})
```

can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord JS - Getting the nickname of a user who dm's the bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56410897/discord-js-getting-the-nickname-of-a-user-who-dms-the-bot)

Comment: I think `member.displayName` is what you are looking for.

Comment: im trying this but it doesn't work, where do you think i need to put it? i tried doing member.user.username || member.displayName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you only want to have one listener for the `message` event, so try this code:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content === 'test'){
        message.channel.send("works")
        console.log("logged the message")
    }
// insert choices from below here
})
```

If you want it to listen for a member being tagged

```js
const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first()

if (mentionedMember){
    message.channel.send(`${mentionedMember}`)
}
```

Now if you want it to listen for username instead of @username

```js
const args = message.content.slice().trim().split(' ')
const guild = message.guild
args.forEach(arg => {
    const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.user.username.toLowerCase() === arg.toLowerCase())
    if (member) {
        message.channel.send(`${member}`)
    } else {
        return
    }
})
```

To listen for displayName

```js
const args = message.content.slice().trim().split(' ')
const guild = message.guild
args.forEach(arg => {
    const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.displayName.toLowerCase() === arg.toLowerCase())
    if (member) {
        message.channel.send(`${member}`)
    } else {
        return
    }
})
```